# VIM Commands Display

Tags: linux, vim

I long while ago (when I was in collage) I used VIM a bit.  I have not used it since and would like to get back into using it.  I remember there being a way to split the screen within VIM to show common commands on the bottom portion of the screen.   I've searched a while and cannot find how to set this up.

Preferably I would like one that I can edit.

Comment: I'm curious what editor have you been using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for "`:help quickref.txt`"?

If you want to force the help window to open on the bottom instead of the top you may do "`:bo help quickref.txt`" (`:bo` is short for `:botright`.)

If you want to be able to edit this help file after you have opened the help window, you can use something like "`:saveas ~/quickref.txt`", then open that file in the future (with "`:split ~/quickref.txt`") instead of running the help command.

See:

```
:help :botright
:help :saveas
:help :split
```